# Verify type, properties of Linq object with T anonymous parameter in function

Tags: linq

In C#, I have a public function that can pass a `List<T>`. The problem that how to verify the type of `T`, get the properties of object in every case?

```
/// <param name="olddatas">The list of T Linq object, that need to 
/// convert in some column </param>
/// <param name="convertedColumn">example,divide by comma: 
/// "column1,column2,column3"</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static List<T> ConvertData<T>(List<T> olddatas, string convertedColumn)
{
    foreach (var olddata in olddatas)
    {
        //Pase the type of olddata?
        //Get the property of every column in convertedColumn parameter?
    }
    //return new List<T> with some column data in olddatas are changed
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your types share a base class or interface, you can [constrain your method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) to that interface, and access members of the interface directly.

If they are unrelated types of `T`, then you might want to consider using a separate method overload for each type.  This is far more maintainable than the mess that arises from checking the types inside of a method and handling each type individually.

That being said, you might want to consider just using Linq's `Select` method instead of your own `ConvertData<T>`.  `Select` is intended for mapping operations - converting data from one form to another.

Comment: The class from Linq sql don't share a base class, have a number of class equal with the number table in database,so that I can't create a separate method overload for each type.